Warning: An error occurred during models config fetch
I have a Strapi project hosted on a DigitalOcean droplet, linked to a DigitalOcean database. The project is live on the server, and after restarting the project using PM2, I encountered the following error:
“Warning: An error occurred during models config.”
Despite this, I am able to log into the admin panel and see the Content tab, but none of the content is visible. The error keeps appearing, and I’m unsure of the cause.
Do you have any ideas on what might be causing this or how I can resolve it?
Let me know if you’d like any further edits!
